# How to limit the height of a List inside a Form in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm curious, how can we set the height of a `List` inside a `Form`? I have a SwiftUI form where I would like there to be an arbitrary list of items that the user can interact with, and some controls below that, which I would like to always be on-screen. The natural inclination would be to write some code like this:

```swift
struct ShortListInForm: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<20) {
                    Text("Item \($0)").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200) // Sets height of the contained Texts (WTH!?)
            
            Button("Do Something") {
                // Do something based on selections above.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SwiftUI is applying the frame to each of the rows of the list, which is pretty surprising and not what I'm looking for. Removing the `.frame` also has an undesired result (the list expands to the size of the full contents, and my button gets pushed down, off-screen).

Interestingly, if I replace the Form with a VStack, things work the way I would expect, but with non-Form styling (and semantic consequences), which I don't want. How can I solve this, keeping a List inside a Form? Less ideally, can I solve this with some other Views replacing the List but keeping a Form as the top level View?

Comment: don't use Form and List at the same time, since Form is basically the same as list with `insetGrouped` modifier. So select one of them: Form or List. Also if you are looking to place the button at the bottom of the screen, consider using `.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom)` for your list or form

Answer (score 0):

One solution (in the less ideal category) is to replace the `List` with a `VStack` in a `ScrollView`, applying the `.frame` to the `ScrollView`. So, something like this:

```swift
struct ShortListInForm: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<20) {
                        Text("Item \($0)").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 100)

            Button("Do Something") {
                // Do something based on selections above.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Playing around with this some more, I see that if I include views below the `ScrollView` such that the Form contents have become larger than the device height, then you will have nested `ScrollView`s (one being the implicit one in the `Form`) and then your scroll gestures arguably become a bit ambiguous. Less arguable, sometimes the behaviour isn't correct (eg when the Form inertial scrolling is still active). So maybe this is why Apple might discourage scrolling Lists within a Form.

Comment: `ScrollView  { LazyVStack` would be a more adequate alternative to List.